# Why is a project created in VS2012 not editable in Blend4 + SketchFlow

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, expression-blend-4

I created a project/solution in VS 2012. I open the same solution in Blend but it doesn't allow me to edit it in the designer - I only can edit the XAML directly.

I'm lost. What's going on?

**EDIT**: I read somewhere that Blend requires "Any CPU" - I verified that this is set.

**EDIT2**: It works with .NET4.0. Does this mean that .NET4.5 is not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It needs the blend for vs2012 preview in order to edit it, however .xaml and .xaml.cs files don't really have any difference between .net4 and .net45, so there isn't anything to stop you creating a solution in vs2010 and including the same files, so that you can use blend to edit it.